# How to optimize this IP to Location lookup query?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization

```
UPDATE tracker SET t_loc_id=(SELECT cb_loc_id FROM city_blocks WHERE INET_ATON(t_ip) BETWEEN cb_start_ip_num AND cb_end_ip_num LIMIT 1);
```

There are about 300K records in `tracker` and about 3.6M records in `city_blocks`. It's been running for over 30min now.

I've got unique indexes on `cb_start_ip_num` and `cb_end_ip_num` already.

Any way I can speed it up?

---

Okay, I let it run for about 2 hours and it only did about 9K records.

Comment: For starts: Take out the select portion and do a 'desc' to find out if its properly indexed.

Comment: @ethrbunny: `desc` on what? Determine if which table is indexed? The tracker table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jcole.us/blog/archives/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/

I converted my IP ranges into polygons and added a spatial index, as per the article above, then ran my update query:

```
UPDATE tracker JOIN city_blocks ON mbrcontains(cb_ip_poly, pointfromwkb(point(inet_aton(track_ip),0))) SET t_loc_id=cb_loc_id
```

Which ran in 45 seconds the first time, 8 the second, vs the estimated 10 hours to 4 days that the other query would have taken.

The article also mentions blockhead's solution, but it still ran atrociously slow. Can't figure out why... I don't know if my indexes were broken (I tried rebuilding them) or it didn't like being in a subquery or something??

Speaking of subqueries...this solution doesn't work well at all with a subquery. I figured a subquery would have been faster because I could add the limit 1 and it wouldn't have to join everything to everything, but that doesn't appear to be the case. Technically without the limit it would have to continue searching to see if the are other potential matches/ranges the IP falls within, but I guess it doesn't really matter in this scenario because everything's properly indexed and there's only 1 bucket it can fall in to.

Comment: Thanks for the article, I'll give it a try. It could potentially be my rescuer!

Answer (score 3):

Create an index on the upper bound column (`cb_end_ip_num`) and find the first row for which that value is greater than or equal to the given value.

`SELECT * FROM city_blocks WHERE  cb_end_ip_num >= 123456789 LIMIT 1`

I've used this for maxmind, and it works very well.

Comment: I think you need an `ORDER BY` on there, no? This assumes there are no gaps in the IP ranges. I'm using the maxmind DB too.

Comment: This is true...this assumes there are no gaps.

Comment: This appears to run equally slow :\

Comment: It is indeed odd. Oh well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Make sure you create the index on the upper bound column as stated by blockhead.  I also created an index on the lower bound column, and then a combination index on the upper and lower bound column.  It's working fast for me.