# How to improve MySQL query execution time

Tags: mysql

I am having an issue that with my query, it is taking around 14 seconds to execute, and I need it to be faster.

Is there anyway I can optimize it?

```
SELECT *
FROM large_table
WHERE (
INET_ATON( 'record number' )
BETWEEN INET_ATON( starting_number )
AND INET_ATON( ending_number )
)
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: what is the table structure?? What are your indexes???

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to optimize this IP to Location lookup query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7559929/how-to-optimize-this-ip-to-location-lookup-query)

Comment: Thank you Alex, let me have a deep look into this as I have more than 3 million current records of IPs in my list right now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Guys ! I have done research on Alex link and it was great solution but I can't add integers to my all 4 million IP Address records as it was something time consuming. 
I have solved my specific issue with http://php.net/explode and I just explode IP address and then remove last number and search on varchar based column and my query get results in less than a second. I am currently going with this solution. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

Even if the the column used as criteria/filter is indexed it would still result in FULL SCAN of table because of INET_ATON() function. try this.

```
    SELECT INET_ATON(`record number`)
    FROM large_table
    WHERE 
    'record number' 
    BETWEEN starting_number 
    AND ending_number 
    LIMIT 0 , 30
```